# How to implement multiple test cases for the same exception in JUnit 4

Tags: java, testing, junit

i'm implementing some tests in JUnit 4 and i don't know to code multiple tests for the same exception.

When the expected output is, for example, a float i initialize the array with the inputs and the expected results, then i populate the results' array and finally i use assertArrayEquals(). It looks like this:

```
@Test
public void testing() throws Exception {
    float[] inputs = {10.24f,20.23f};
    float[] expectedResults = {10.2f,20.2f};
    float[] results = new float[inputs.length];


    for (int i=0;i<inputs.length;i++) {
        results[i]=methodBeingTested(inputs[i]);
    }

    assertArrayEquals(expectedResults, results);

}
```

I want to do this but for an exception.
There must be a better way than creating a method for the each test case where an Exception is expected.
Can anyone enlighten me please?

Answer (score 2):

I would separate cases when mathod should success from those when method should fail. Below sample using [catch-exception](https://code.google.com/p/catch-exception/), [zohhak](http://zohhak.googlecode.com) and [assertj](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/)

```
import static com.googlecode.catchexception.CatchException.caughtException;
import static com.googlecode.catchexception.CatchException.verifyException;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import com.googlecode.zohhak.api.TestWith;
import com.googlecode.zohhak.api.runners.ZohhakRunner;

@RunWith(ZohhakRunner.class)
public class MyTest {

    @TestWith({
        "10.5",
        "-2.8"
    })
    public void should_throw_exception(float input) {
        verifyException(new ObjectUnderTest()).methodBeingTested(input);

        assertThat(caughtException())
                    .isInstanceOf(IllegalArgumentException.class);
    }

    @TestWith({
        "10.24, 10.2",
        "20.23, 20.2"
    })
    public void should_succeed(float input, float expectedOutput) {
        assertThat(methodBeingTested(input)).isEqualTo(expectedOutput);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With JUnit4 you can tell the framework that an exception is expected for a test method with the following syntax:

```
@Test(expected = Exception.class)
public void test() {}
```

Just replace `Exception.class` with the exception type you are expecting to be thrown in your test.

In your test method you may also catch the exception and put an assertion in the catch block.

```
int exceptionThrown = inputs.length;
for (int i=0;i<inputs.length;i++) {
  try {
    // code that should throw an exception
  } catch (SomeException e) {
    assert.assertTrue(e instanceof SomeException)
    exceptionThrown--;
  }
}
assert.AssertEquals(exceptionThrown, 0);
```

But if some array should throw an exception I think a better way to make you tests is to separate those that pass w/o exception from those that throw one in separate methods to have things cleaner and more readable.

Comment: I already know how to test for an Exception with a single input Olivier, what i want to know is how to test for a array of inputs that would cause an Exception, kinda like the example i've posted, but instead of float-pointing numbers i would be expecting the exceptions.

Comment: I've tried the same method with the @Test(expected=Exception.class) annotation, but it only tests the first element of the array ending the test as passed.

Comment: Olivier Meurice, all the elements in the inputs array are expected to throw the same exception.

Comment: What i'm looking for is to run all the tests in the same method instead of creating a test method for each input.